# how can I control the font size of an infobox in a shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

I want to make the text in an info box smaller than the text on the rest of the dashboard. Here is the dashboardBody part of the code:

```
dashboardBody(fluidRow(        

      box(
         title = "Box 1",
         width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE,
         status = "primary",
         uiOutput("myUiOutput")
      ),
      box(
         title = "Box 2",
         width = 12,
         solidHeader = TRUE,
         status = "warning",
         plotOutput("myPlot")
      ),
      infoBox(title = "my info box title", 
              value = "my info box message",
              subtitle = NULL,
              icon = shiny::icon("copyright"), color = "black", width = 12,
              href = NULL, fill = FALSE) 
 )) #<-end dashboardBody
```

I tried adding this tag before the Box 1 code, but it did not work:

```
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
    .info-box .logo {
    font-family: "Georgia", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8px;
  }
'))),
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution is to set `font-size` as a percentage for cases when you don't know upfront what your current `px` size is, e.g.

```
 value = tags$p("my info box message", style = "font-size: 50%;")
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree, it's strange that css commands don't work. But try to write

```
value = tags$p(style = "font-size: 10px;", "my info box message")
```

instead of your `value`, to make it an inline style command.